How to prevent \vspace* from introducing unwanted "glues" when invoked at the top or bottom of a page
Consider the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper, lines=10]{geometry}

\begin{document}

1 \par 2 \par 3 \par 4 \par 5 \par
6 \par 7 \par 8 \par 9 \par 10 \par \vspace*{\baselineskip}
11 \par 12 \par 13 \par 14 \par 15 \par
16 \par 17 \par 18 \par 19 \par 20 \par

\end{document}

I used the geometry package with the lines=10 option, so that there should be exactly 10 lines in one page. Then I used \vspace* after the 10th line, expecting the vspace to be put at the top of the second page. However, the vspace "dragged" the 10th line to the second page unexpectedly as well. Similarly, if I put the \vspace* after the 9th line, then the 9th line will also be "dragged" to the second line.
After some investigation, I found in this answer that \vspace* will introduce a \nobreak. After deleting it through some sorts of patching, the vspace is no longer "glued" to the line after it (i.e. putting it after the 9th line works as expected). However, it is still glued to the line before it.
So, how should I prevent \vspace* from gluing itself to the line before it? Or, is there a better way to achieve the desired effect other than some ugly patching?
Some background information: I would like to typeset some Japanese light novels (in vertical writing direction) in LaTeX. Conventions for vertical typesetting are completely different from horizontal typesetting. For example, spaces between paragraphs should never be stretched, and orphans/widows are not avoided at all. It is perfectly legitimate for a vspace (or more precisely, "hspace") to appear at the top (or more precisely, right-hand side) or bottom (or more precisely, left-hand side) of a page.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

\vspace{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip} ?

If the goal is to add a gap at the top of the next page but not add any space the bottom of this page, \pagebreak\strut\par should do the trick.

@UlrikeFischer It somewhat works when placed after the 10th line, but an extra \baselineskip will be added, so I have to write \vspace*{0pt} if what I really what is a \baselineskip vspace. It works as intended when placed after the 9th line (along with the patch to remove \nobreak). It is more desirable to have a consistent behavior at different places, because I won't know the exact position of the vspace in advance most of the time.

@JohnKormylo My goal is to create a command that will add an empty line without interfering with other lines, no matter where the command is invoked. This trick is only useful when you know the position of the empty line in advance...

I don't get an extra space (or do not see what you mean) but you could also simply insert a \penalty 0  to allow a break again.

Try \par\strut\par (assuming \parskip=0pt).  Extra \pars are ignored.
